# Does CiviVolunteer need volunteer sub-contact type?

Tags: custom-fields, civivolunteer

We have found that it is more cumbersome than it is worth to use a 'volunteer' sub-contact type classification. One reason is profiles assume one contact type and even working with Caldera Forms it over-complicates matters. Simply, 'Volunteer' is not a distinct enough categorization, at least for us to make it a sub-type.

Are there any effects on the project management side of CiviVolunteer where this is not advised?

We would simply change the custom field set to apply to individuals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it doesn't have an answer.

The "Volunteer" sub-contact type ships with CiviCRM core and is, for the most part, unrelated to CiviVolunteer. The "Volunteer Information" custom field set ships with CiviVolunteer merely as a demonstration of the "slider" functionality. That it is configured as a "Volunteer" rather than an "Individual" field set is arbitrary.